# Average/Percentile of each value against column and save result in new column using pandas built in function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns

```
df
hr  count   
2   53
3   1586
4   890
5   833
6   209
```

I want to take average/Percentile of each value of column and want to store result in new column. Currently I am using this way.

```
    df['avg'] =    (df['count'] / df['count'].sum()) * 100
    df
    hr  count   avg 
    2   53      1.484178
    3   1586    44.413330
    4   890     24.922991
    5   833     23.326799
    6   209     5.852702
```

I want to this by built in function like `mean()` . How can I achieve this with built in function?

Comment: There's a groupby hack but AFIK sklearn has that funtionality.

Comment: This is not average/mean you are calculating percentile

Comment: What you are doing is the correct way to do this, AFAIK there is no percentile function that does what you want. the `mean` is a different thing since you'd calculate the mean of the whole column giving you one value.